# Builing Xamarin iOS in Azdo Pipeline for iOS 15

Tags: azure-devops, xamarin.ios, azure-pipelines

We are currently building our Xamarin Forms project locally with a Mac build machine using Xcode 12.5 and our iOS devices are running a max version of iOS 14.8.

With iOS 15 now released we are seeing a message on one of the test devices that is running iOS 15, telling us that the app cannot be run and needs updating.

[image: iOS 15 error message explaing the app needs to be updated by the developer]

Looking at the various other posts on this situation I suspect if I upgrade my local xcode to v13 I'll be able to build an iOS 15 version but the error message is coming from an app package built using the XamariniOS task in Azure DevOps

```
- task: XamariniOS@2
      displayName: 'Build Xamarin.iOS solution OurSol.sln'
      inputs:
        solutionFile: '**/*OurSol.sln'
        configuration: ${{variables[format('{0}_{1}', parameters.environment, 'BuildConfiguration')]}}
        signingIdentity: 'iPhone Distribution'
        signingProvisioningProfileID: ${{variables[format('{0}_{1}', parameters.environment, 'ProvisioningProfileId')]}}
```

How do I ensure that task is using Xcode. The pipeline is using macOS-latest image

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-latest'
```

Comment: Don't use `macOS-latest` specifically use `macOS-11`, `macOS-latest` still points at an old image. Check this list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software

Comment: Ye I found that about 5 minutes after posting the question but it was too early to answer my own question. macOS-latest not lastest then :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the hosted agents documentation, you will see that `macOS-latest` is not the same as `macOS-11`.

Currently `macOS-latest` points at `macOS-10.15`.

I've personally stopped using `macOS-latest` as it as you just experienced doesn't yield predicable results, especially when they switch the versions.

A good practice in CI is to select versions yourself to be able to easily reproduce builds.